# index out of bound exception in autocomplete textview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am getting index out of bound exception in autocomplete textview on

```
arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

while using setOnItemClickListener.

I want to get the string which has been selected from the list of autocomplete textview.

```
ArrayList<String> servicaNameList = db.getServices(flag, editTextServiceName.getText().toString());
serviceAdapter = new ServiceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.service_list, servicaNameList);
editTextServiceName.setAdapter(serviceAdapter);
editTextServiceName.setThreshold(1);
editTextServiceName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        System.out.println("name = " + arg0.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }
});
```

This is the adapter class:

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;

public ServiceAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, arrayList);
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parrent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parrent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView42 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView42);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    String name = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.textView42.setText(name);
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView42;
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant code bits.. Based on this the only thing anyone can say is `arg0` has less than `position` number of items which is why you get the exception

Comment: please provide both code and logs

Comment: give the ServiceAdapter code

Comment: Where are you adding service names in `servicaNameList`?,at the time of click there is only one item in your list.Check if you are updating the list anywhere else.

Comment: servicaNameList is the list of items that is displayed in autocomplete textview. When I need to update the list?

Comment: could you please share the complete code for adpater?

Comment: Please refer this for better solution  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: This link does not provide any information regarding setOnItemClickListener and adapter

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal Please add your autocomplete textview part..

Comment: @sunilsunny editTextServiceName is the autocomplete textview only.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal 
ok understood can you please check this 

 `String selected = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);`
 `int pos = Arrays.asList(servicaNameList).indexOf(selected);`
 `System.out.println("name = " + servicaNameList.get(pos));`

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use position and arraylist like below to get the item selected.

```
ArrayList<String> servicaNameList = db.getServices(flag, editTextServiceName.getText().toString());
    serviceAdapter = new ServiceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.service_list, servicaNameList);
    editTextServiceName.setAdapter(serviceAdapter);
    editTextServiceName.setThreshold(1);
    editTextServiceName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            System.out.println("name = " + servicaNameList.get(position));
        }
    });
```